# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when using several alias columns

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have a table with 5 defined columns (id, colA, colB, colC, colD), all are of datatype `decimal(18, 3)` except `id`.

```
SELECT 
    [id],
    [colA], [colB], [colC], [colD],
    colA - colB as length,
    colC - colD * 2 as width,
    colA + width - length as colMod0
FROM 
    [dbo].[main]
ORDER BY
    _main.id;
```

When I execute this code, I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I tried to cast and convert but without success. Length, width and colMod0 are all alias columns.

Comment: I have rolled back your question, because your edit would invalidate any answer already given.

Comment: You cannot use a column alias in another expression and you introduced another error using "_main" in the order by clause. Simply put, your query has syntax errors and will not run to produce the runtime error you claim. But the error you encounter is discussed on a daily basis in SO and many other places. Simply search on that message for ideas to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message has nothing really to do with types.  Rather, it is just telling you that an alias cannot be reused in a select statement at the same level.  One solution is to just repeat the expressions for `width` and `length`:

```
SELECT [id], [colA], [colB], [colC], [colD],
    colA-colB AS length,
    colC-colD*2 AS width,
    colA + (colC-colD*2) - (colA-colB) AS colMod0
FROM [dbo].[main]
ORDER BY _main.id;
```

An alternative to this would be to place your current query into a CTE, and then subquery it to use the aliases:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [id], [colA], [colB], [colC], [colD],
        colA-colB AS length,
        colC-colD*2 AS width
    FROM [dbo].[main]
)

SELECT [id], [colA], [colB], [colC], [colD], length, width,
    colA + width - length as colMod0
FROM cte
ORDER BY _main.id;
```

Comment: what if i need to use the length in few more alias column? @tim

Comment: Either you have to repeat as my answer does, or you can subquery your original query, and then refer to the `width` and `length` aliases.  In general, I don't like the subquery option, because performance degrades.  An example of where I might be inclined to use it would be something like the Haversine formula, which is large, illegible, and is something you don't want to repeat.

Comment: @Vincent I have given you a subquery option in my edited answer.